# Tap Gesture + Long Press Gesture both not working Together

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uigesturerecognizer

I want use tap gesture and long press gesture together in a view. But my problem is that I can't able to run tap gesture action on tap. But Long press gesture is working fine.

Here is code snippet.

```
            UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture=[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ontappLongPressGesture:)];
            longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration=0.6;

            longPressGesture.delegate=self;
            [cell.view addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];

            UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellSelected:)];
            //[gesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:longPressGesture]; //I have tried with this line also but not working
            gesture.delegate=self;
            [cell.view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```

Also I have set delegate method also

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
return YES;
}
```

This method is getting called on long press

```
- (void)ontappLongPressGesture:(id)sender{

    //Long press code here

}
```

But this method is not getting called on tap

```
-(void)cellSelected:(id)sender {

     //Single tap code here

}
```

Comment: I tested this and removed the delegate and it worked.

Comment: Try removing the delegates. You're telling the gestures that they can fire simultaneously. This is not the case. You only should have the tap OR the long press. not both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't specified what type of view your putting these gestureRecognizer's on, however since you are calling it "cell", I'm assuming its on a UITableView?

You need to make sure you set the `cancelsTouchesInView` flag if so:

```
gesture.cancelsTouchesInView=NO;
```

Answer (score 2):

You either need to use one of these two ways.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    // test if our control subview is on-screen
    if (cell.view.superview != nil) {
        if ([touch.view isDescendantOfView:cell.view]) {
            // we touched our control surface
            return YES; // handle the touch
        }
    }
    return NO; // ignore the touch
}
```

Here you need to specify the view for which you want the gestureRecognizer.

Or you can also use these lines of code

```
gesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO; 
longPressGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

Hope it will help you.